# How to get variable from one class to another in Joomla?

Tags: php, variables, joomla

How do I get the `getState` variable from one class to another?

Exactly I need to get value of "filter.search". How can I do that?

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
abstract class SroHelper 
{
    public static function checkIP() 
    {
        SroModelItems::getState(filter.search); ---- ??
    }

}

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
class SroModelItems extends JModel 
{
    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) 
    {
        $this->setState("filter.search", $jform["search$dbextra"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure, but I belive it is `$this->getState()->get("filter.search");`

Comment: There won't be a state for filter.search if you're not in the Items MVC path, in what context are you trying to reference this views state?

Answer (score 0):

You have two modules to store information in the session automatically from a get / post request and then to read it back:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->getUserStateFromRequest($key, $request)

JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState($key, $value);
```

Just ensure you are saving the information before you try to retrieve it!